# How to return a numpy arrays with expected shape from large csv file?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, dask, data-analysis

My expected shape of the return array S1 are (20,10). Why it is (22,10)? (2)How can I extract some rows from df0 and df1 and to construct a new array efficiently?

The csv files is not large but they can be more than 8G and the parameter M can be larger than 2000.

My code is as follows.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

# Define df's
file0 = './dataset_zeros.csv'
file1 = './dataset_ones.csv'
df0 = dd.read_csv(file0,dtype="str",header=None)
df1 = dd.read_csv(file1,dtype="str",header=None)
#Drop the index
df0 = df0.drop(0,axis=1)
df1 = df1.drop(0,axis=1)

def generate_S(file0, file1,init,M,N_in,N_out):
    a = int(M/N_out) # if M=20, N_out=2, then a=10
    #Read csv files
    df0 = dd.read_csv(file0,header=None)
    df1 = dd.read_csv(file1,header=None)
    # Drop the index
    df0 = df0.drop(0,axis=1)
    df1 = df1.drop(0,axis=1)
    
    start = init*a
    end = (init+1)*a

    # extract a=10 rows from df0 (Part 1)
    train_X0 = df0.loc[start:end,:] # select rows
    train_X0 = train_X0.iloc[:,:10] # select columns
    train_X0 = train_X0.values # Convert dataframe to array
    
    # extract a=10 rows from df1 (Part 1)
    train_X1 = df1.loc[start:end]
    train_X1 = train_X1.iloc[:,:10]
    train_X1 = train_X1.values
    

    # concatenate the two parts to a new array
    new_X = np.concatenate((train_X0, train_X1), axis=0)
    
    #================================
    #res = new_X.reshape(M,N_in)
    res= new_X
    return res

# Examples of Parameters
init = 2
M = 20
N_in = 10
N_out =2

# Call the function
S1= generate_S(file0,file1,init,M,N_in,N_out)
```

The dataframe df0 and df1 looks like
[image]

Then I run

```py
S1.compute_chunk_sizes()
```

The result is
[image]

Comment: "My expected shape of the return array S1 are (20,10). Why it is (22,10)?" Why do you expect this shape? What happens when you display the contents of the array? How does that compare to the expected contents? Can you reproduce the problem with a smaller file? It appears that you get the data by reading a file, but we don't have the file, so there's no way we could possibly tell you why it produces the result that it does. "How can I extract some rows from df0 and df1 and to construct a new array?" Well, what is the rule that tells you which rows to use? Did you try just slicing the data?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have written a function `generate_S()`to generate several numpy arrays from the two files. That is the reason I want to expect that shape. I can not reshape the array from dataframe, or do not understand why I get more  extra rows.

Comment: Did you try looking at the output files with a text editor or spreadsheet program? Do they contain what you expect them to contain? You say that the result from `generate_S` should have 20 columns, but it has 22 instead. Yes? And the reason you expect 20 columns is because your plan is to take 10 columns from one source and 10 columns from the other, and put them together, yes? Well - did you verify that the things you're putting together actually do have 10 columns each? What do `train_X0` and `train_X1` look like *after* each assignment? Do you see *where* the problem occurs?

Comment: What I'm trying to get you to do is to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code properly, so that you can present a proper understanding of the problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "And the reason you expect 20 columns is because your plan is to take 10 columns from one source and 10 columns from the other, and put them together, yes?"  Yes I merge them together. But each has 10 rows, and the result array should be 10+10=20 rows. The number of column of the returned array is correct.

Comment: So you're telling me that if you put `print(train_X0.shape, train_X1.shape)` *immediately before* the `new_X = np.concatenate((train_X0, train_X1), axis=0)` line, you see correct values? But if you put `print(new_X.shape)` *immediately after* that line, you don't see what you expect?

Comment: I have tried before, it is as follows.    ```new_X.SHAPE:
(nan, 10)
new_train_y.SHAPE:
(nan,)```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241235/discussion-between-jiadong-and-karl-knechtel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"My expected shape of the return array S1 are (20,10). Why it is (22,10)?" This is because I did not understand and check the index `start` and `end`: In `df.loc[]`, both the `start` and `end` are taken into account! For example, if I want to extract 10 rows, I should set `start=20; end=29`, instead of `start=20; end=30`.

The correct piece of code is:

```py
start = init*a
end = (init+1)*a - 1
# extract a=10 rows from df0 (Part 1)
train_X0 = df0.loc[start:end,:] # select rows
```

Therefore, the function `generate_S()` is modified as follows.

```py
def generate_S(file0, file1,init,M,N_in,N_out):
    a = int(M/N_out)
    #Read csv files
    df0 = dd.read_csv(file0,header=None)
    df1 = dd.read_csv(file1,header=None)
    # Drop the index
    df0 = df0.drop(0,axis=1)
    df1 = df1.drop(0,axis=1)
    
    start = init*a
    end = (init+1)*a - 1
    
    # extract a=10 rows from df0 (Part 1)
    train_X0 = df0.loc[start:end,:] # select rows
    train_X0 = train_X0.iloc[:,:10] # select columns
    train_X0 = train_X0.values # Convert dataframe to array
    
    # extract a=10 rows from df1 (Part 1)
    train_X1 = df1.loc[start:end]
    train_X1 = train_X1.iloc[:,:10]
    train_X1 = train_X1.values
    
    new_X = np.concatenate((train_X0, train_X1), axis=0)
    new_X.compute_chunk_sizes()
    
    #Test
    print("new_X.SHAPE:")
    print(new_X.shape)
    
    res = new_X.reshape(M,N_in)
    return res
```

The function will return an array with shape `(M, 10)` (in this code, `M=20`). Part 1 of problem is solved.

Part 2 of the problem is : `new_X.compute_chunk_sizes()` in the function `generate_S()` is very time consuming, when the csv files are large. Even worse, it gives a wrong result. For my large csv files, the shape of the `new_X` is:

```py
new_X.SHAPE:
(1170, 784)
```

But the expected one is `(a, 784)`. Here, `a=10`. It seems that the function `generate_S()` operate on each chunk! (There are 117 chunks in this example.) I really want to it operate only once.

I hope to find a correct and efficient method to implement this function.

=====

I have found the right method. `dask` is not necessary here. To generate the array from the large csv file, I can use keywords `skiprows` and `nrows` in `pandas.read_csv()`. Here is my new version of the function. It read lines from two csv files and merge them into one array.

```py
import pandas as pd

def generate_S(file0, file1,init,M,N_in,N_out):
    a = int(M/N_out)
    #Read csv files
    df0 = pd.read_csv(file0,header=None,skiprows=(init-1)*a, nrows=a)
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file1,header=None,skiprows=(init-1)*a, nrows=a)
    # Drop the index
    df0 = df0.drop(0,axis=1)
    df1 = df1.drop(0,axis=1)
    #0
    train_X0 = df0.iloc[:,:-1] # select columns
    train_X0 = train_X0.values # Convert dataframe to array  
    #1
    train_X1 = df1.iloc[:,:-1]
    train_X1 = train_X1.values
    
    new_X = np.concatenate((train_X0, train_X1), axis=0)
    return new_X
```

The problem is solved.